# Bootstrap 4 accordion keeps opening when trying to close it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the example accordion in the bootstrap 4 [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example) but it is not working properly. After debugging, I realised that the `show` class is removed and added again when you try to close the card.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxKiK.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTSaI.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzEOh.jpg 
I tried using the break on attribute modification in the dev tools but I couldn’t find where the problem is coming from

Edit: this is the code snippet I copied from the bootstrap documentation

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add your code snippet.

Comment: can you show me that code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was from how I integrated the template that I am using. For anyone using metronic 7, make sure plugins.bundle.css is loaded after style.bundle.css

```
<!--begin::Global Stylesheets Bundle(used by all pages)-->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.bundle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--end::Global Stylesheets Bundle-->
```

**not this**

```
<!--begin::Global Stylesheets Bundle(used by all pages)-->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/style.bundle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--end::Global Stylesheets Bundle-->
```